# Check/Uncheck of check-boxes upon certain events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code :
**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checkbox_servers_list').click(function(){
    var checkedValues = $('.group-list:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(checkedValues);
      var check_hosts = ["192.168.33.50", "192.168.33.100"]; // This value will be dynamic via ajax call.
      for (each in check_hosts){
          $(".host-list:checkbox[value='"+check_hosts[each]+"']").attr("checked", true);
        }
  });

});
```

and the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


 <div id="group-list-id" class="checkbox_servers_list"><div class="col-md-12">
   <input type="checkbox" value="all" name="checkbox" class="group-list" id="group-checkbox_0">
   <label for="group-checkbox_0">all</label>
 </div> <div class="col-md-12">
 <input type="checkbox" value="mumbai" name="checkbox" class="group-list" id="group-checkbox_1">
 <label for="group-checkbox_1">mumbai</label>
</div> <div class="col-md-12">
<input type="checkbox" value="okhla" name="checkbox" class="group-list" id="group-checkbox_2">
<label for="group-checkbox_2">okhla</label>
</div> <div class="col-md-12">
<input type="checkbox" value="ungrouped" name="checkbox" class="group-list" id="group-checkbox_3">
<label for="group-checkbox_3">ungrouped</label>
</div> <div class="col-md-12">
<input type="checkbox" value="vagrant1" name="checkbox" class="group-list" id="group-checkbox_4">  
<label for="group-checkbox_4">vagrant1</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12"> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="bangalore" name="checkbox" class="group-list" id="group-checkbox_5">
  <label for="group-checkbox_5">bangalore</label>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-12"> 
 <input type="checkbox" value="vagrant2" name="checkbox" class="group-list" id="group-checkbox_6">  
 <label for="group-checkbox_6">vagrant2</label>
</div>
</div>

<hr>

  <div id="host-list" class="checkbox_hosts_list">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="checkbox" value="192.168.33.50" name="host-checkbox" class="host-list" id="host-checkbox_0">
      <label for="host-checkbox_0">192.168.33.50</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="checkbox" value="192.168.33.10" name="host-checkbox" class="host-list" id="host-checkbox_1">
      <label for="host-checkbox_1">192.168.33.10</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="checkbox" value="192.168.1.57" name="host-checkbox" class="host-list" id="host-checkbox_2">

      <label for="host-checkbox_2">192.168.1.57</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="checkbox" value="192.168.1.59" name="host-checkbox" class="host-list" id="host-checkbox_3">
      <label for="host-checkbox_3">192.168.1.59</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="checkbox" value="192.168.33.100" name="host-checkbox" class="host-list" id="host-checkbox_4">
      <label for="host-checkbox_4">192.168.33.100</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <input type="checkbox" value="192.168.1.58" name="host-checkbox" class="host-list" id="host-checkbox_5">
     <label for="host-checkbox_5">192.168.1.58</label>
   </div> 

 </div>









</body>

</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I click on any check box from the top section, respective check-boxes in the bottom section should get checked(which is happening) but when I un-check a check-box from the top section respective check-boxes in the bottom section should get unchecked(which is not happening).

I tried adding this in the beginnning of the js function.

```
    $(".host-list:checkbox").attr("checked", false);
    and 
$(".host-list").prop("checked", false);
```

but it even stops the execution of the first feature.

P.S:
demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/06d6kumt/2/) of what is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a list items to be checked, first marks all as unchecked

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkbox_servers_list').click(function(){
        var checkedValues = $('.group-list:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        console.log(checkedValues);
        var check_hosts = ["192.168.33.50", "192.168.33.100"]; // This value will be dynamic via ajax call.
        $(".host-list:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
        for (each in check_hosts){
            $(".host-list:checkbox[value='"+check_hosts[each]+"']").prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is `attr` and `prop` have this inconsistency ?

Comment: @Nagri see https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery+prop+vs+attr&oq=jquery+prop+v&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5313j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Try this to uncheck:

```
$('.host-list').find('input').prop('checked',false);
```

UPDATE: You should check your click function and then get values, so inside for I added a conditional.

```
    for (each in check_hosts) {
        if($(".host-list:checkbox[value='" + check_hosts[each] + "']").attr("checked")){
            $(".host-list:checkbox[value='" + check_hosts[each] + "']").attr("checked", false);
        }else {
            $(".host-list:checkbox[value='" + check_hosts[each] + "']").attr("checked", true);

        }
   }
```

Comment: Checks my update, you have to control checkbox with `.attr("checked")`